# Polars series logical operation

Tags: rust-polars

```
    #[test]
    fn test_polars_series2() {
        // Create three Series with boolean data
        let s1 = Series::new("bool_series1", &[true, false, true, false]);
        let s2 = Series::new("bool_series2", &[true, true, false, false]);
        let s3 = Series::new("bool_series3", &[true, false, false, false]);
    
        let mut series_vector: Vec<Series> = Vec::new();
    
        series_vector.push(s1.clone());
        series_vector.push(s2.clone());
        series_vector.push(s3.clone());
    
    
        let mut last_series = Series::default();
        let mut result_series = Series::default();
    
        // Loop through the vector using a for loop
        for element in &series_vector {
            if last_series == Series::default() {
                last_series = element.clone();
            } else {
                // Perform element-wise comparison
                result_series = last_series.equal(element).unwrap().into_series();
            }
            println!("Element: {}", element);
        }
        println!("Result Series: {:?}", result_series);
    }
```

I need to generate a series that is the logical result of a set of series. However, Polars does not implement logic for series. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try to use `fold`: https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/user-guide/expressions/folds/ or use logical expr https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/user-guide/expressions/operators/#logical

Comment: Fold seems that will solve the problem. Conditional solve for fixed number of columns.

Answer (score 0):

```rust
use polars::prelude::*;

fn test_polars_series2() {
    // Create three Series with boolean data
    let s1 = Series::new("bool_series1", &[true, false, true, false]);
    let s2 = Series::new("bool_series2", &[true, true, false, false]);
    let s3 = Series::new("bool_series3", &[true, false, false, false]);

    let s1_name = s1.name().to_string();

    let lf = DataFrame::new(vec![s1, s2, s3]).unwrap().lazy();

    

    let df = lf.with_column(
        fold_exprs(
            col(&s1_name),
            |acc, x| Ok(Some(acc.bitand(&x).unwrap())),
            [col("*").exclude([&s1_name])],
        )
        .alias("logical_result"),
    ).collect().unwrap();

    println!("{df:?}");


}
```

```
// will show:
┌──────────────┬──────────────┬──────────────┬────────────────┐
│ bool_series1 ┆ bool_series2 ┆ bool_series3 ┆ logical_result │
│ ---          ┆ ---          ┆ ---          ┆ ---            │
│ bool         ┆ bool         ┆ bool         ┆ bool           │
╞══════════════╪══════════════╪══════════════╪════════════════╡
│ true         ┆ true         ┆ true         ┆ true           │
│ false        ┆ true         ┆ false        ┆ false          │
│ true         ┆ false        ┆ false        ┆ false          │
│ false        ┆ false        ┆ false        ┆ false          │
└──────────────┴──────────────┴──────────────┴────────────────┘
```